# How do I shutdown a computer on my network?

Tags: networking, batch, shutdown

I want to shutdown a computer on my network at home. When I try the usual 'shutdown' command, I get the 'Access denied (5)' message. In what way must my computer be connected with the other computer in order for me to take control?

Comment: I put it there now, hopefully someone will be able to help.

Comment: Is the secondary logon service started on the remote computer?

Comment: How do you connect to these computers? Which application displays the error message? Do you use MSTSC.EXE to remotely connect to the computers?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is if you are on a windows computer you could type: "shutdown -i" and that will open up this little window, from that window, if your at school per se you would just click the computer or computers that you want to shutdown and then give your reason and then press shutdown. or if your not at school, say you want to prank a friend, you could just add their IP address to the add computer button and I believe that would allow you to send the shutdown command to said person. I hope this helps in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use

```
shutdown /s /m \\computer1 /t 0
```

That will shutdown the computer `computer1`, provided it is on the same network. You will most likely need domain admin rights to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [psshutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) for this.

Comment: I don't want to use another program for this. It's possible to shutdown other computers on your network, they just need to be connected in a specific way. I just want to know what I have to do to get them to be connected like school computers or work computers.